# Call linked server procedure

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

If I call procedure on linked server, I get the following error:

Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

It works in SSMS, also it works with classic asp, but not here. I have found some similar questions, but no answer. And I wont(can't) connect directly to linked server and execute procedure locally. It must be executed as : myLinkedServer.Database.dbo.myProcedure

Any idea?

```
 using (SqlCommand getOutput = new SqlCommand())
        {

            getOutput.CommandText = "myLinkedServer.Database.dbo.myProcedure";
            getOutput.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            getOutput.CommandTimeout = 300;
            getOutput.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(getOutput))
            {
                da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
                da.Fill(exportData);//here error happened
                conn.Close();
                da.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
getOutput.CommandText = "EXEC myLinkedServer.Database.dbo.myProcedure";
getOutput.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

When calling a procedure on linked server, command type should be as text.

Comment: If this answer is a solution, please mark it as a solution.